# #beautifulsoup How to export each article into different word file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to export each article into different word file using beautifulsoup?

I am trying to scrap all  the articles and export them one by one into different word files

suppose if there are 1000 articles i want 1000 word files

here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#to loop over all 199 pages
for i in range(1,199):
    URL = "https://trumpwhitehouse.archives.gov/remarks/page/"

    r = requests.get(URL+str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

    #to get all the links from the first page of news headlines
    links=[]
    for news in soup.findAll('h2', class_='briefing-statement__title'):
        links.append(news.a['href'])
    
    #followed the link from the first page and extract article text
    for link in links:
        page=requests.get(link)
        sp=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
        article=sp.find("div",class_="page-content").find_all("p")
        for d in article:
            print(d.get_text())
    
    #sleep time to 3 seconds to overcome blocking
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `try-except` block when you are writing to `text` file and you can write custom message if `exception` occurs or you can print.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
os.mkdir("US_DATA")
os.chdir("US_DATA")
path=os.getcwd()
for i in range(1,199):
    URL = "https://trumpwhitehouse.archives.gov/remarks/page/"

    r = requests.get(URL+str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

    #to get all the links from the first page of news headlines
    links=[]
    for news in soup.findAll('h2', class_='briefing-statement__title'):
        links.append(news.find("a")['href'])
    
    #followed the link from the first page and extract article text
    for link in links:
        page=requests.get(link)
        sp=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
        article=sp.find("div",class_="page-content").find_all("p")
        try:
            for d in article:
                with open(path+"//"+link.split("/")[-2]+".txt","a",encoding="utf-8") as data:
                    data.write(d.get_text()+"\n")
        except:
            print(link)
```

Output: (Local Folder):

[image]